# Django ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Through a OneToOneField Relationship

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have a setup with models that I have not come across in my research. It's a model with a through relation table that is a OneToOne relation.

The issue is the Admin interface works fine when setting the reservations in the form.

```
 class AgentForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Agent
```

But creating a Basic ModelForm leads to the error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use podman.BladeReservation's Manager instead.
```

---

**models.py**

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), help_text=_('A name for the node.'), max_length=128)
    hostname = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Hostname'),
        max_length=255,
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name', 'hostname']

class Blade(Node):
    serial_number = models.CharField(_('Serial Number'), max_length=255, unique=True)
    uuid = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('UUID'),
        help_text=_('Node UUID'),
        max_length=50,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    ...

class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=128, help_text=_('This name is a friendly handle for humans.'))
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name=_(u'Slug'),
        help_text=_('Uri identifier. This name is the lookup key for Automation'),
        max_length=100,
        unique=True
    )
    ...

    blades = models.ManyToManyField('podman.Blade', related_name='blades', through='podman.BladeReservation')
    ...

class BladeReservation(models.Model):
    blade = models.OneToOneField('podman.Blade')
    agent = models.ForeignKey('podman.Agent')
    reserved_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

---

**admin.py**

```
class AgentAdmin(CompareNoDuplicates):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
    inlines = [BladeReservationInline]
    filter_horizontal = ('blades',)
    list_display_links = ('__str__',)
    preserve_filters = True

class BladeReservationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BladeReservation

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['formfield_callback'] = partial(self.formfield_for_dbfield, request=request, obj=obj)
        return super(BladeReservationInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        agent = kwargs.pop('obj', None)
        formfield = super(BladeReservationInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "blade" and agent:
            formfield.queryset = formfield.queryset.filter(chassis__pod__in=[p for p in agent.container.pods.all()])
        return formfield
```

---

My current track is making a WizardView just to get a custom form flow, But its not ideal. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the part of your views there you're dealing with the form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you get this error, because you try to create `Agent`-`Blade` relationship directly, however [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) say:

> You can’t just create a relationship between a Person and a Group -
>   you need to specify all the detail for the relationship required by
>   the Membership model. The simple add, create and assignment calls
>   don’t provide a way to specify this extra detail. As a result, they
>   are disabled for many-to-many relationships that use an intermediate
>   model. The only way to create this type of relationship is to create
>   instances of the intermediate model.

But since your `reserved_until` field in `BladeReservation` model is allowed to be blank this might help you:

```
class BladeReservation(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta():
        auto_created=True
```

Comment: Awesome! This works for my needs in this case. As long as I keep the fields as nullable it works.

Comment: I thought this was the magical solution at first. Only problem is that it will create a new migration that tries to delete the existing m2m table.
If you delete the previous migrations, it just won't add the extra fields in the m2m table.

Comment: @oailloud's comment is very important. One workaround though is to `makemigrations` before you set auto_created, and then add `managed = False` to prevent Django's migration engine from trying to mess it up. Of course, you need to temporarily remove `managed = False` if you need to change the table structure, but it "works".